# I can't use a third-party dll C# ASP .NET 4.8

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dll

I have a project where a link to a third-party dll is plugged in (Project->Add Link)
Locally everything works, checks the library, see the license key - everything is super.

But if I try to deploy the project to local IIS it all stops working.
Tried remote debug to iis, writes that the product is either not installed or there is no activation key. But it works fine in Visual Studio.
The dll is connected to the path C:\Program Files\ABBYY PassportReader SDK1.5\ABBYY.PassportReaderSdk.dll

Comment: `But it works fine in Visual Studio` - because on your computer, the product is installed, and there is activation key?

Comment: @GSerg I am trying to deploy in iis on the local computer where it is installed ABBYY.PassportReaderSdk.dll(C:\Program Files\ABBYY PassportReader SDK1.5\ABBYY.PassportReaderSdk.dll)

. Thought that if the product was installed on the computer, it would also work in the local iis

Comment: If the dll is native, a possible cause is missing vcredist package.

Comment: @JonasH I installed ABBYY PassportReader SDK.msi and add reference to dll in Visual Studio

Comment: Did you make the installation available to all users? Does the account under which the IIS is running have access to the dll and the license key? Can you see in [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) any file or registry access errors?

Comment: @GSerg i found solution and add to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the Application Pool for my site.
I changed it to Local System and everything worked